# pasar números selecconados de una matriz a un vector?

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código. Este recorre una matriz, valida si el numero obtenido de la matriz es primo,si lo es lo asigna a un vector.

Tengo un problema lógico, el vector se rellena con el mismo numero obtenido en la matriz, necesito recorrer la matriz e ir asignado los valores primos al vector.

No se que validación hacer o que estructura para que me recorra bien la matriz e ir asignando los primos.

```
public int[] algoritmoSeleccion() {
    // int menor, pos, tmp, cont = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
            for (int m = 0; m < v.length; m++) {
                    if (esPrimo(matriz[i][j])) {
                        v[m] = matriz[i][j];
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    return v;

}
```

Una mano, se los agradeciera.

Comment: El vector que contiene dentro al comenzar la función? O siempre esta vació?

Comment: El vector esta vació,solo tiene definido el tamaño.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int[] algoritmoSeleccion() {
    // int menor, pos, tmp, cont = 0;
    int vector_pos = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
             if (esPrimo(matriz[i][j])) {
                        if(vector_pos < v.length){
                           v[vector_pos] = matriz[i][j];
                           vector_pos++;
                         }
                    }
        }
    }

    return v;

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Esta seria una posibilidad:

```
  public int[] algoritmoSeleccion() {
    // int menor, pos, tmp, cont = 0;
    int vectorIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {          
            if (esPrimo(matriz[i][j])) {
                v.add(vectorIndex,matriz[i][j]); // Agrego un elemento a la posicion desea
                vectorIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

Otra opción es usar el método `.add()` que te agrega un elemento **siempre a la ultima posición del vector** y aumenta su tamaño de forma dinámica (Lo te ahorra de definir un tamaño desde el principio). Mas información [Aquí](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/vector_add.htm)

Comment: En un principio use la clase Vector pero no supe como organizar el Vector con seleccion shot. Al final lo pase un arreglo unidimensional.

Comment: Muchas gracias.